# Change volume of specific app with CSCore

Tags: c#, cscore

I would like to change the audio volume of an application with CSCore. The following code is already pretty close to what I want, but it changes the volume of all applications at the same time. Instead, I would like to select one specific app only and change its volume. How could I do that?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int pID;

            using (var sessionManager = GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow.Render))
            {
                using (var sessionEnumerator = sessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator())
                {
                    foreach (var session in sessionEnumerator)
                    {
                        using (var simpleVolume = session.QueryInterface<SimpleAudioVolume>())
                        {
                            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
                            {
                                if (process.ProcessName == "foobar2000" && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
                                {
                                    pID = process.Id;
                                    //Console.WriteLine(pID.ToString());
                                    //simpleVolume.MasterVolume = 0.2f;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static AudioSessionManager2 GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow dataFlow)
        {
            using (var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator())
            {
                using (var device = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(dataFlow, Role.Multimedia))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("DefaultDevice: " + device.FriendlyName);
                    var sessionManager = AudioSessionManager2.FromMMDevice(device);
                    return sessionManager;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you call `ISimpleAudioVolume::SetMasterVolume` what do you expect it to do ?

Comment: @Aybe Well according to the documentation, it allows to change the volume of a session. But I just cannot figure out how to target a specific session.

Comment: It's better to look at MSDN instead.

Comment: I was suggesting you MSDN because once you read it you'll realize that the sessions you think are sessions aren't user sessions, try the other interfaces if cscore has them implemented.

Comment: What do mean, "user sessions"? From what I've read on the CSCore documentation, a session basically represents the audio channel or audio output of an application in the [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac3Jh.png](Windows volume mixer). As you can see on that screenshot, there is one device with multiple sessions. So first you have to loop through all devices in "MMDeviceEnumerator" and then you have to loop through all sessions that are active on that device.

Comment: For the 3rd time, read MSDN

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old question but I had a sort of similiar issue and it took me an hour or two to figure out how this works. A look at CSCores [unit tests](https://github.com/filoe/cscore/blob/master/CSCore.Test/CoreAudioAPI/AudioSessionTests.cs) made it a lot easier

The author of the question basically had everything in place except for figuring out which `AudioSessionControl` belongs to which application (Because it has no PID and the `AudioSessionControl.DisplayName` is always blank, at least for me).

The trick is to get `AudioSessionControl2` from the `AudioSessionControl` and then get the associated process from its PID.

```cs
using CSCore.CoreAudioAPI;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

using var device = MMDeviceEnumerator.DefaultAudioEndpoint(
    DataFlow.Render, 
    Role.Multimedia);

using var sessionManager = AudioSessionManager2.FromMMDevice(device);
using var enumerator = sessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator();

//skipping first as it seems to be some default system session
foreach (var sessionControl in enumerator.Skip(1))
{
    using var sessionControl2 = sessionControl.QueryInterface<AudioSessionControl2>();
 
    using var process = Process.GetProcessById(sessionControl2.ProcessID);
    using var volume = sessionControl.QueryInterface<SimpleAudioVolume>();

    Console.WriteLine($"Volume of {process.ProcessName} : {volume.MasterVolume}");
}
```

[image]

To change the volume, just set the value of `MasterVolume`